# Query regarding unbounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let (sn) be a sequence such that sn > 0 for all n. Prove that
if (sn) is unbounded, then SN = {sn : n > N} is unbounded for all
N ∈ N.

This is a question I have to solve. I'm struggling to come up with an approach, though. I tried to use mathematical induction to prove the result, but found that it can get very complicated to do so. Is there an easier way to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the contrary:

There exists a $N \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ s.t.

$S_N=${$s_n |n>N$ } is bounded , i.e.

$0<s_n < M$, positive, real for all $n >N$.

Let  $\max (s_1,s_2,......,s_n) =: m$.

Then

$s_n \le \max(m, M)$, $n \in\mathbb{Z^+}$ , i.e.

{$s_n| n \in N$} is bounded.

Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $(s_n)$ is unbounded, then for all $M$, there is $N$ s.t. $s_N\geq M$. In other words, for all $M$, there is $\ell\in SN$ s.t. $\ell\geq M$. This mean that $SN$ is unbounded.